# The type or namespace name 'frmAbout' does not exist in the namespace 'DevExpress.Utils.About'

Tags: devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

Just upgraded to DevExpress 18.1.5, and my app won't compile because DevExpress.Utils.About.frmAbout doesn't resolve. Did DevExpress replace this with something else?

```
    private void iAbout_ItemClick(object sender, DevExpress.XtraBars.ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        DevExpress.Utils.About.frmAbout dlg = new DevExpress.Utils.About.frmAbout("~");
        dlg.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DevExpress response:

Yes, we have reworked our frmAbout dialog in version 18.1. Now you can show the dialog using our DevExpress.Utils.About.AboutHelper class as follows:

```
DevExpress.Utils.About.AboutHelper.Show(DevExpress.Utils.About.ProductKind.DXperienceWin, new DevExpress.Utils.About.ProductStringInfoWin(DevExpress.Utils.About.ProductInfoHelper.PlatformWinForms));
```

Comment: Hmm... interesting. Do you have any real reasons for showing the "DevExpress About Window" in "Your Company App"?